# que função seria útil para remover dados do xml com php ou js?

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Estou fazendo um sistema com php,js e xml,com um formulário php onde o usuário adiciona eventos e eles são gravados automaticamente no xml

Este é o adiciona.php

```
$campoTitulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$campoLocal = $_POST['local'];
$campoData = $_POST['data'];
$campoHorario = $_POST['horario'];
$campoDescricao = $_POST['descricao'];
//Nome do arquivo
$nomeArquivo = "eventos.xml";
// versão do encoding xml
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
// retirar os espaços em branco
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
// gerar código ??
$dom->formatOutput = true;
// carrega o arquivo
$dom->load($nomeArquivo);
// recupera nó principal
$root = $dom->documentElement;

$evt = addEvento($dom, $campoTitulo, $campoLocal, $campoData, $campoHorario, 
$campoDescricao);
// adicionando ao root
$root->appendChild($evt);
$dom->appendChild($root);

// salva o arquivo
$dom->save($nomeArquivo);
// mostrar
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
print $dom->saveXML();

function addEvento($documento, $titulo, $local, $data, $horario, $descricao) {
// criar evento
$evt = $documento->createElement("evento");
// criar nó titulo
$tituloElm = $documento->createElement("titulo", $titulo);
//criar nó local
$localElm = $documento->createElement("local", $local);
// criar nó data
$dataElm = $documento->createElement("data", $data);
//criar nó horário
$horarioElm = $documento->createElement("horario", $horario);
//criar nó descrição
$descricaoElm = $documento->createElement("descrição", $descricao);

$evt->appendChild($tituloElm);
$evt->appendChild($localElm);
$evt->appendChild($dataElm);
$evt->appendChild($horarioElm);
$evt->appendChild($descricaoElm);
return $evt;
}
?>
```

Mas eu preciso de um script para o usuário poder remover seus eventos através de um formulário,onde é mostrado os eventos que ele criou(isso eu já fiz),e um botão de excluir para cada evento.

Comment: Com a própria classe `DOMDocument` você analisa o XML e remove os elementos que desejar.

Comment: Eu ainda estou conhecendo o DOM e o XML,portanto não tenho idéias claras de como manipular o DOMDocument para que o usuário possa remover seus próprios dados